# Is it possible to add new target type in drupal content type?

Tags: drupal, civicrm-entity, civicrm-home

Is it possible to add new target type in drupal content type?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like you are using the Entity Reference field.  The target types, are Drupal Entity types. You can definitely create your own custom entities.

The Drupal Examples module has an entity example:
https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/entity_example%21entity_example.module/group/entity_example/7.x-1.x

Although this doesn't leverage the additional tooling provided by the [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module...

If you are wanting to reference CiviCRM data from Drupal node, install the [CiviCRM Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) module. CiviCRM Entity exposes CiviCRM API entities as Drupal entity types

With that enabled you can reference CiviCRM memberships, contacts etc...Or create new ones, using [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) widget